# Find sum and max of a column from joining 2 tables of same schema in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE 1

```
Name Marks
a    65
b    40
```

TABLE 2

```
Name Marks
c    25
b    70
```

SUM will be (65+40+25+70) &
MAX will be 70

Comment: UNION ALL instead of join. GROUP BY its result.

Comment: What change required if i add condition such as marks > 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use union all to combine two table and then apply aggregation

```
   select sum(marks), max(marks)
    from
    (select * from table1
    union all
    select * from table2)a
where marks>40
```

Comment: What change required if i add condition such as marks > 40

Comment: modifed my answer, check

Comment: @PARTHADEY when you will use condition >40 then what will be in addition result?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
--test in your sql management

--populating test table 

declare @table1 table (name varchar(30), marks int )
declare @table2 table (name varchar(30), marks int )

insert into @table1 values ('a',65)
insert into @table1 values ('b',40)

insert into @table2 values ('c',25)
insert into @table2 values ('d',70)

**--query excluding marks<=40 from sum**

select sum(marks) as 'sum' ,max(marks) as 'max' from 

(
select * from @table1 where marks>40

union

select * from @table2 where marks>40
) table_temp

**--query showing sum, only if sum > 40**


select sum(marks) as 'sum' ,max(marks) as 'max' from 
(
select * from @table1 

union

select * from @table2 

) table_temp having sum(marks) > 40
```

Comment: Thanks - that's pretty much just the same as fa06's answer though? And your two versions for filtering out marks should be equivalent?

Comment: no. there are diferent. depending what do you need to do. filtering result or data before. that is the diference between having and where clauses.